# ¿Cómo optimizar y como utilizar el plugin bootstrap css?

Tags: bootstrap

Cual es la forma correcta de utilizar **bootstrap** para crear el diseño de una plantilla he observado algunos ejemplos de plantilla muy creativas en fin ciertas partes del contenido muy ilustrativo.

He intentado imitar a otras plantillas pero no he tenido éxito o el uso o el orden correcto.

```html
<link href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<section id="features" class="img-block-3col bg-features">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="title">
    <h2>What Makes it Awesome</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy rat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <ul class="item-list-right item-list-big">
      <li class="wow fadeInLeft animated" style="visibility: visible;">
       <i class="icon icon-screen-desktop"></i>
       <h3>Responsive design</h3>
       <p>Your project looks great on any device. Content can be easily read and a user understands freely what you wanted to say him or her.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="wow fadeInLeft animated" style="visibility: visible;">
       <i class="icon icon-drop"></i>
       <h3>Bootstrap 3.1</h3>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy rat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="wow fadeInLeft animated" style="visibility: visible;">
       <i class="icon icon-doc"></i>
       <h3>Cross-Browser Support </h3>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy rat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4">
     <ul class="item-list-left item-list-big">
      <li class="wow fadeInRight animated" style="visibility: visible;">
       <i class="icon icon-diamond"></i>
       <h3>Pure &amp; Simple</h3>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy rat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="wow fadeInRight animated" style="visibility: visible;">
       <i class="icon icon-layers"></i>
       <h3>Documentation</h3>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy rat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="wow fadeInRight animated" style="visibility: visible;">
       <i class="icon icon-bubbles"></i>
       <h3>Creative Design</h3>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy rat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

> La idea es crear este diseño de ciertas partes ilustrativas de estas imágenes.

```html
<img src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-upTfZMYzGP4/WIev-kADSHI/AAAAAAAAAhY/L1Avea3rkosJQqAOY9shlYykDjpAlb8oQCLcB/s1600/aprenderesto.jpg">
<img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-IS2LxmJbzzc/WIev7ChnuXI/AAAAAAAAAhQ/85StbVhCDhId6VYItMYuCF7fuWG4xqrfwCLcB/s1600/ssadsdas4.png">

<img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-tB5DXCUcqK0/WIev7Bxe4XI/AAAAAAAAAhU/Wf6RHBvalkYz8-jzqUEbUlIVb8rWZjH-wCLcB/s1600/ecdsvd.png">
```

Pero no acabo de comprender el uso de **bootstrap** `css` ¿Cual seria la estructura correcta? o cómo implementar su uso.

Comment: Hola podria ayudarte pero debes de ser un poco mas especifico ya que no capto muy bien la idea de lo que realmente deseas realizar. quedo atento

Comment: Hola @Daniel estoy tratando de crear el diseño que están en las imágenes utilizando **Bootstrap** pero no he podido lograr el primer diseño de la imagen... No comprendo muy bien el uso es la primera vez que estoy trabajando con este plugins.

Comment: @Daniel lo que trato de hacer es el diseño de las imágenes utilizando **Booststrap***

Comment: Hola @J.Mick no se si depronto lo que quieres realizar es algo parecido a lo que he visto en link https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-upTfZMYzGP4/WIev-kADSHI/AAAAAAAAAhY/L1Avea3rkosJQqAOY9shlYykDjpAlb8oQCLcB/s1600/aprenderesto.jpg...donde hay una imagen que por ejemplo es un lupa y  lado dice MOTOR DE BUSQUEDA OPTIMIZADO. Si es eso lo que que quieres hacer me avisas,como para no hechar tanta carreta sin confirmar que sea eso lo que necesitas.Quedo atento

Comment: Hola @Daniel si amigo lo que trato de realizar es algo parecido a las imágenes con **Boostrap** pero no he podido lograr si puedes observar mi codigo no lo podido conseguir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo puedes hacer, solo utilizando los estilos proporcionados por bootstrap y agregando algunos nuevos como muestro en el ejemplo:

Debes tomar en cuenta `row` de **Bootstrap** mide 12 espacio si quiero que un objeto abarque media pantalla esta debe ser la definición de mis clases:

Si quiero un renglón dividido en 2 partes iguales 12/2 = 6

- row

  - col-sm-6
  - col-sm-6

Si quiero un renglón dividido en 3 partes iguales 12/3 = 4

- row

  - col-sm-4
  - col-sm-4
  - col-sm-4

Si quiero un renglón dividido en 3 partes iguales 12/3 = 4, y dentro de cada objeto igual se divide en 12 espacios:

- row

  - col-sm-6

    - col-sm-2
    - col-sm-10
  - col-sm-6

Ejemplo de las divisiones en **Bootstrap**

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dividir dos</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      Primer mitad
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      Segunda mitad
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2>Dividir 3</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      Primer parte
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      Segunda parte
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      Tercer parte
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2>Dividir 2 con Sub diviciones</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="col-xs-2">12 35 4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-10">Descripcion etc et cet c etc et cetc Descripcion etc et cet c etc et cetc Descripcion etc et cet c etc et cetc</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      Segunda mitad
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aquí esta el ejemplo parecido a lo que quieres hacer, toma en cuenta que según el tamaño de la pantalla se ve en 2 o en una columna debido a que es responsivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #767676;
  font-weight: 400;
}
h2 {
  font-family: "Brandon", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px!Important;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #30373b;
}
hr {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-top: 4px solid #ebb129!Important;
}
p {
  color: #949494;
  margin-bottom: 0.9375em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.sub-title {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.38em;
  line-height: 1.38;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.icon-big {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #ebb129;
  border: 3px solid #ebb129;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div class="container">
  <h2>What Makes it Awesome</h2> 
  <hr/>
  <p class="sub-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy rat, sed diam voluptua.</p>

  <div class="row">
    <!--  row1 -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <!-- Tomar la mitad de la pantalla1 -->
      <!-- Agrego los renglones -->
      <div class="row">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in icon-big col-xs-2"></span>
        <p class="col-xs-10">Your project looks great on any device. Content can be easily read and a user understands freely what you wanted to say him or her.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-out icon-big col-xs-2"></span>
        <p class="col-xs-10">Your project looks great on any device. Content can be easily read and a user understands freely what you wanted to say him or her.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- / Tomar la mitad de la pantalla 1 -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <!-- Tomar la mitad de la pantalla 2 -->
      <div class="row">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-qrcode icon-big col-xs-2"></span>
        <p class="col-xs-10">Your project looks great on any device. Content can be easily read and a user understands freely what you wanted to say him or her.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera icon-big col-xs-2"></span>
        <p class="col-xs-10">Your project looks great on any device. Content can be easily read and a user understands freely what you wanted to say him or her.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- / Tomar la mitad de la pantalla 2 -->
  </div>
  <!-- / row1 -->
```

Comment: Hola @CristinaCarrascoAngulo gracias, he aprendido la utilización de dos partes iguales. En el primer ejemplo me he confundido un poco pero no existe problema lo estudiaré. Solo una duda o dos, en la segunda imagen, existen dos partes pero no son iguales el texto tiene un ancho mucho más menor al de la imagen. **En la segunda duda?** En la tercera imagen, es una imagen de fondo pero esta, está dividida en cuatro partes como lo podria implementar utilizando el mismo mecanismo si no es mucho pedir... Agradezco su respuesta he aprendido mucho gracias a ud. Saludos :)

Comment: Me olvidaba el diseño de la imagen compartida la observe aquí en [este sitio web](http://www.wix.com/templateses/ads-and-mrkt-firm-es)

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">   
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <img class="img img-circle" src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/horadeaventura/images/f/f9/Lupa.png/revision/latest?cb=20130805152151&path-prefix=es" width="100px" height="100px">                        </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">MOTOR DE BUSQUEDA OPTIMIZADO</div>

            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
                <img class="img img-circle" src="http://horacioreyes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/solarcoin.png" width="100px" height="100px"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3">SOPORTES PARA IMPUESTOS Y MONEDAS GLOBALES</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

@J.Mick En `bootstrap` el sistema de rejilla trabaja con cuatro tipos de clases, dependiendo de la clase con la cual tu trabajes se vera en tu pantalla dependiendo de unas medidas estandarizaras, este código basico que hice se ve un poco igual a lo que quieres pero quizás en tu pantalla se va a ver diferente. Para no dejarte en la mismas te dejo este link `http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp` para que practiques, y también te recomiendo mucho usar los estilos CSS para que le des ese toque que haga que se vea muy parecido.

Una pagina por mas que tenga `bootstrap` jamas evitara tener estilos `css.`