# ¿Cómo dividir dos partes desiguales utilizando bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, css3

> Siguiendo los ejemplos de **Cristina Castro** en una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45809/c%C3%B3mo-optimizar-y-como-utilizar-el-plugin-bootstrap-css/46464#46464) anterior basándose en el mismo tema **Bootstrap.**

El problema está en que los dos contenidos `div` se dividen en partes iguales como se puede observar en este **ejemplo:**

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #767676;
  font-weight: 400;
}
h2 {
  font-family: "Brandon", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px!Important;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #30373b;
}
hr {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-top: 4px solid #ebb129!Important;
}
p {
  color: #949494;
  margin-bottom: 0.9375em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
img {
  height: auto;
  border: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.sub-title {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.38em;
  line-height: 1.38;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.icon-big {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #ebb129;
  border: 3px solid #ebb129;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
  <h2>What Makes it Awesome</h2> 
  <hr/>
  <p class="sub-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy rat, sed diam voluptua.</p>

  <div class="row">
    <!--  row1 -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <!-- Tomar la mitad de la pantalla1 -->
      <!-- Agrego los renglones -->
      <div class="row">
        <img src="https://ioyby2hf25e3sg55t3muegr1-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Switch-Onepage-Business-WordPress-Theme.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- / Tomar la mitad de la pantalla 1 -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <!-- Tomar la mitad de la pantalla 2 -->
      <div class="row">
        <h3>Title One Content</h3>
        <p>Your project looks great on any device. Content can be easily read and a user understands freely what you wanted to say him or her.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <h3>Title One Content</h3>
        <p>Your project looks great on any device. Content can be easily read and a user understands freely what you wanted to say him or her.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- / Tomar la mitad de la pantalla 2 -->
  </div>
  <!-- / row1 -->
</div>
```

La idea es crear el mismo estilo del ejemplo pero en partes desiguales donde la imagen ocupe más espacio que el contenido del texto, como muestra el diseño de esta imagen:

[image: Imagen de ejemplo]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los grids de bootstrap se manejan en la escala del 1 al 12, donde el 12 es de pantalla completa y el 1, es la fracción más pequeña que maneja bootstrap,

Para lograr lo que tu estas diciendo bien podrías cambiar las dimensiones de los cols a algo similar a esto

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #767676;
  font-weight: 400;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  border: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://ioyby2hf25e3sg55t3muegr1-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Switch-Onepage-Business-WordPress-Theme.png">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="row">
    <h3>Title One Content</h3>
    <p>Your project looks great on any device. Content can be easily read and a user understands freely what you wanted to say him or her.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Aquí](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) te dejo un poco mas la información acerca de los grids de bootstrap

Comment: para ver bien la división del grid ejecuta el código y después dale click a página completa.
Espero te ayude

Comment: Hola @eezzekl gracias por responder, edite tu pregunta eliminando llamado de script innecesarios por otra parte utilizando la imagen no el texto ya que no podría visualizar si el diseño sería el deseado. En conclusión si el diseño el deseado pero existe un problema en el texto que se encuentra a lado de la imagen el texto está demasiado pegado a la derecha en el caso de la imagen no ocurre aquello la imagen como se puede observar amigo.

Comment: Como te comenté, Boostrap maneja un sistema de cols- del 1 al 12, ya seria unicamente que vayas variando los tamaños hasta encontrar el que mas se te acomode, acabo de agregar en la respuesta un enlace la informacion de los grids de bootstrap

Comment: Ok amigo gracias solo falto añadir un container en inicio principal y el cierre al final del contenido lo he solucionado añadiendo un container `<div class="container"></div>`

Comment: que bueno que lo hayas solucionado

Answer (score 2):

Para poder dividir la pantalla en partes iguales o desiguales utilizando Bootstrap, no es necesario agregar ningún estilo adicional, solo basta con  indicar el tamaño de tus columnas, en este ejemplo que te dejo esta a 6 y 6 aquí puedes separar al tamaño que tu necesites:
te dejo una liga para que puedas escribir codigo boostrap sin basura: https://www.layoutit.com/build

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```